# Searching for two arguments Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am working on a search with two text fields. It searches for two things (right now location and description) and only shows the entries (listings) that match both of them.
I would like the second text field to also search for title, so it should look for description and title. How would that work?

This is what I have right now

listing.rb

```
def self.locsearch(search_location, search_description)
  return scoped unless search_location.present? || search_description.present?
  where(['location LIKE? AND description LIKE?', "%#{search_location}%", "%#{search_description}%"])
end
```

home.html.erb

```
<%= form_tag findjobs_path, :controller => 'listings', :action => 'locsearch', method: :get do %>
  <%= text_field_tag :location, params[:location] %>
  <%= text_field_tag :descripiton, params[:descripiton] %>
  <%= submit_tag "Search", name: nil %>
  <% end %
```

listings_controller.rb

```
def index
@listings = @listings.locsearch(params[:location], params[:description])
end
```

Also, my locsearch method right now uses the or || condition. How would I implement the "and" condition? (If I change the || to && I get the error" undefined method or variable scroped)

Comment: Use `&&` for AND. The error "undefined method or variable **scroped**" is obviously caused by a typo.

Comment: I'm still getting
undefined local variable or method `scroped'

Comment: Look harder. You have `scroped` in there somewhere. The error message should show you where.

Comment: No, it's the only time I use scroped. Also, when I use || I don't get the error.
The error highlights this line
return scroped unless search_location.present? && search_description.present?

Comment: Also, I tried to learn more about scroped and from what I found it should be scoped

Comment: Right... that's why I said it was an obvious typo. "Scroped" is not a word. Compare the working line `return scoped unless search_location.present? || search_description.present?` to the broken line `return scroped unless search_location.present? && search_description.present?`. At the time `||` was changed to `&&`, an **r** snuck into `scoped` to become `scroped`, which broke your code and caused the error. Simple typo.

Comment: Otherwise is there a way to display an error message or so unless a listing matches both location and description?

Comment: Okay so this is what I have now
return scoped unless search_location.present? && search_description.present?

Is that the correct syntax and spelling? If so, I still get the same error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure you want to use `unless`

`unless` is used only if you want to execute a specified code if the condition(s) is false.

And `scoped` is used along with a model.

```
Model.scoped
```

You can refer the [Apidock](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/NamedScope/ClassMethods/scoped) or [Github](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/12756)

You can write `return scoped` only if u have defined `scoped` as a local variable or a method.

You can also see [scope for databases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7333198/how-to-get-a-scope-for-all-database-rows-in-rails-3)

Comment: Thanks Richa
Is there another easier way to display an error message or so unless a listing matches both location and description?